# Why does overflow need to be set to "hidden" in order for nav bar to be visible?

Tags: html, css

If one checks the following code:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

For a nav bar where elements are floated to the left, it seems imperative to set the overflow property of "ul" as "hidden". If this property is not set then the nav bar disappears completely. Why is this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you dont do so, the `<ul>` is not inside the text flow I guess.
The right way to do this here is to not use the overflow attribute but `float: left;`

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with what is known as a **block formatting context**.
Establishing a new BFC means that it is responsible for its own layout, especially when dealing with floated elements.

You could also have written `overflow: auto`. Basically, any other overflow value than `visible` (which is default) would make the nav bar visible.

Read more about BFC's here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context